# set typescript for setState generic typing

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having a hard time passing the `setValidate` to Child Component and facing an error of:
***Status is not a function***.

What could be gone wrong?

https://codesandbox.io/s/q-59841382-controlledcomponent-forked-8jcnm?file=/index.js:176-236

I tried this method, and nothing seems wrong. But when I'm using typescript, it won't work.

**Parent Component**

```
const [validate, setValidate] = useState(false);

console.log(validate)

<TextField
  value={''}
  status={setValidate}
  onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}
/>;
```

**Child Component** (TextField)

```
export const TextField: React.FC<types.TextFieldType> = ({ status }) => {
  const [valid, setValid] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleBlur = () => {
    setValid(!valid);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    status(valid);
  }, [valid, status]);
};
```

**TextFieldType**

```
export type TextFieldType = {
  status: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>> 
}
```

Comment: What is `CommonType`?

Comment: it's just bunch of other types for the TextField, but it doesn't do anything to the status

Comment: If you wanted to create a sandbox, you should have created one with TypeScript template (that reproduces this error / warning). It is available in sandbox. We see no issue in your current sandbox code.

Comment: I don't need to create sandbox, I'm just referring the sandbox with the passing setState

Comment: [I cannot reproduce your error](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-wright-e6p8r?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: It seems like `CommonType` is the culprit. So, try to create a sandbox in TypeScript to reproduce the issue. Or you can show what `CommonType` is really doing. A suggestion: it reads better to name the setter function as `setStatus` instead of `status`.